# Ender 5 Plus Bowden tube keeps popping out

Tags: creality-ender-5, bowden

My new Ender 5 Plus' Bowden tube keeps popping out of its socket on the extruder mid-print, I've tried several times and it keeps doing it even though it's locked into place securely at the start every time. Is this a known issue? And how do I resolve it?

I just got it so I doubt it's the coupler, I replaced it with a spare as my first solution, I did notice that it got almost stringy plastic around it whenever it gets popped out.... could that be indicative of what the problem is?

Answer (score 4):

The coupler for the Bowden tube is probably worn out or the tube end has been scraped so that the coupler can't grab it or you have left out the clamp on the coupler.

The coupler has a sleeve that when pressed down releases the Bowden tube.  There is a C-shaped clip that should go between the top lip of the sleeve and the body of the coupler that prevents the sleeve from moving and should help hold the tube more firmly.  Make sure this is installed.

If the tube outside is visibly worn with scrape marks (this is rare), it might help to cut a few cm off the end so that a fresh section is gripped by the coupler.  Be sure to cut the end flush so that there is no gap between the heat break and the Bowden tube or you will have other problems.

Alternately (and this is more likely), the coupler itself is worn out, possibly with bent or broken-off teeth.  If this is the case, you will need to replace the coupler.

Comment: I just got it so I doubt it's the coupler, I replaced it with a spare as my first solution, I did notice that it got almost stringy plastic around it whenever it gets popped out.... could that be indicative of what the problem is?

Comment: That sounds like you have a gap between the bowden tube and the heat break.  When you pull it out, make sure there is no plastic above the heat break, and if there is, clean it out.  Then make sure the tube goes all the way in.  If the tube end is not flat, it might be good to trim it.  One of the easiest ways to do that is to insert it into a spare coupler and cut the end flat with the end of the coupler using a razor blade.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what part is the heat break (I've never really had to deal with the tube and couplers before)

Comment: The heat break is between the bowden tube and the heated part of the hot end.  The bowden tube should go all the way down to the bottom of the hole below the coupler.  If there's a gap, molten plastic will collect between the bowden tube and the hot end and solidify and make a mess.  If your tube was slipping, that probably already happened, so now it needs to be cleaned out.

Comment: but It's the coupler on the extruder end that's problematic.

Comment: @TristanAdams Does it have a clip on it that stops the collet from moving? You can print one if there weren't any included - they are small so you should be able to print one before the tube comes loose.

Comment: yes even then it popped out still

Comment: Ahh.  If it's the driven end of the extruder rather than the hot end, at least there's no mess to clean out.  If it's slipping, either it is loose and adding the clip will help, or it is worn as I explained in the answer.

Comment: well since I tried the clip all that's left is the snip.

Answer (score 1):

OK well I feel silly, it turns out it wasn't fully pushed into place, I pushed it in feeling it lock and thought it was secure, when it actually wasn't, pushing it in till it feels locked up twice resulted in it being properly secured. (sorry if my description doesn't make a lot of sense, I'm not good at that kind of thing, so I'm trying my best.)